# Do python have a item lore reader module?

Tags: python

So I am working on a project, where I can grab values from an API. I am trying to get the "lore" from Minecraft items (example further down). Now I want to create something that looks a bit like this:

[image: picture]

If there is a module, where all I have to do is fill information in to make that lore, that would be awesome! But if there isn't, I have to just design it myself. But before I can do that, I need to be able to "read" lore data. Here is an example of what an item could look like:

```
§7Strength: §c+7 §8(Strong +7) §7Crit Damage: §c+7% §8(Strong +7%) §7Health: §a+100 HP §7Defense: §a+65 §9Growth V §7Grants §a+75 §c❤ Health§7. §9Protection V §7Grants §a+15 §a❈ Defense§7. §7All stats of this armor piece §7are doubled while on the End §7Island! §5§lEPIC LEGGINGS
```

Now §7 is a gray color, and §8 is dark grey, etc. More could be found on [this](https://www.digminecraft.com/lists/color_list_pc.php) link.

Thanks
- Simon

Comment: Where do you want the lore to pop-up ? into the terminal ?

Comment: No, it will either be that you hover over it and it will show. Or it will just display "information" about the item, so I will have a  picture of the item, then below a little 'box' with the lore, translated.

Comment: Meh, I've retaged your question with [php] tag. I do not know php though...

Comment: oh, you think I would need PHP for this?

Comment: I don't think, but there is no code and no context to start from.

Comment: yeah, thats why I was making a thread here if there is a module that can convert that text into colored text, I will dig deeper down in google to see  if I can find it.